How do I add a cms block for a particular category above the pagination toolbar and below the products grid?
How do I add a cms block for a particular category above the pagination toolbar and below the products grid?
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="accessories.stand.out" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">accessories_stand_out</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock> 

app/design/frontend/cb/vannicholas/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_id_4.xml
I have added it for the category 4. I don't get any error neither the CMS block is rendering

Simply override list.phtml in your theme and add code in phtml file for call cms block over there.
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
to
app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Module_Catalog/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
and add your code above this line
    <?= $block->getChildBlock('toolbar')->setIsBottom(true)->toHtml() ?>
<?php if ($categoryId = yourId) {
       echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('accessories_stand_out')->toHtml(); 
} ?>


Since it's for a particular category you can't edit this list.phtml as it will affect every categories

You can edit brother, just add condition based on current category id

I guess below one work for get category id $categoryId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);

Does this count as Magento standardized way? What if client comes up with multiple categories like these?

so how you can manage with xml? you need to create seprate xml based on category id, yes this is the way only. you can do one thing, configure categories id from admin, add one configuration for add comma separated category ids and if match those id against current category id then show this block.

Of course, We can modify list.phtml as per our need. there are many ways to achive this kind of functinality, you can give yes/no in category for show this block also. its upto you and client, whatever best and easier way
